# ANTLR4 Grammar mathematical operator associativity and order of operations

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I am attempting to create an ANTLR4 grammar to carry out mathematical operations. However, I'm finding some difficulty balancing the order of operations alongside operator associativity. (e.g. x+y+z is right-associative should be understood as x+(y+z) and subtraction is left associative, so x-y-z should be understood as (x-y)-z ).

This example defines the operations with correct associativity.

```
expr
   :  value = INTEGER #Integer
   |  value = VARIABLE  #Variable 
   |  <assoc=right> left = expression  op = '^' right = expression #Operation
   |  <assoc=left>  left = expression  op = '/' right = expression #Operation
   |  <assoc=right> left = expression  op = '*' right = expression #Operation
   |  <assoc=right> left = expression  op = '+' right = expression #Operation
   |  <assoc=left> left = expression  op = '-' right = expression #Operation
```

However, the order of operations dictates that multiplication and division are evaluated with equal precedence, from left to right. The same goes for addition and subtraction.
This example maintains the order of operations, but denies the ability to add the associativity.

```
expr
   :  value = INTEGER #Integer
   |  value = VARIABLE  #Variable 
   |  <assoc=right> left = expression  op = OP_POW right = expression #Operation
   |  left = expression  op = ('/' | '*') right = expression #Operation
   |  left = expression  op = ('+' | '-') right = expression #Operation
```

Any attempts I've made to fix this end up using left-recursive rules. Is there a way to maintain operator associativity AND the correct order of operations using ANTLR4? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want `+` and `*` to be right associative? That seems pretty unusual. Anyway it is unclear to me what the results of having two operators with the same precedence but different associativity would even be. What would you want the parse trees to be for e.g. `a + b - c + d` or `a - b + c - d`? `(a + ((b - c) + d)` and `((a - b) + (c - d))`? Isn't that the same as assigning a higher precedence to `-` than `+`?

Comment: I think I may have been misguided. Thank you for your help, I had received some misguided advice and have since gone with the second example shown. I hadn't realised that all + - / * operations are all left associative, but rather thought that only / and - were left associative due to their commutativity. Thank you for the quick and clear response! It's a big help.